# How can I interact java program using python

Tags: java, python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to execute java program using python considering inputs and outputs both](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9333637/how-to-execute-java-program-using-python-considering-inputs-and-outputs-both)

I want my python variable should receive all the output of java program and using that variable i will display the output on the screen. also if there is a input to java program, I want that user will enter the input which will be stored in my python variable and using this variable, I want to pass the input to java program.. What should I do?? Please help..

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [Jython](http://www.jython.org/) instead, it was designed with Python-Java interoperability in mind. Alternatively, use the standard input/output facilities of the operating system for writing strings back and forth between the two programs, take a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9333637/how-to-execute-java-program-using-python-considering-inputs-and-outputs-both).