# Python - Execute Java - Could not find or load main class

Tags: java, python

I followed the [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9333791/4314952) to execute a java program from python

```
import os.path, subprocess
from subprocess import STDOUT, PIPE


def compile_java(java_file):
    subprocess.check_call(['javac', java_file])


def execute_java(java_file, stdin):
    java_class, ext = os.path.splitext(java_file)
    cmd = ['java', java_class]
    process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT, universal_newlines=True)
    stdout, stderr = process.communicate(stdin)
    print(stdout)


compile_java(os.path.join('model', 'classification', 'Model.java'))
execute_java('Model', '5 6 7 8')
```

The python code compiles the `/model/classification/Model.java` without problems. But when the python code executes the java program, **Java can not find or load the main class Model**. Executing `java Model` in the command line in the same directory (with the compiled version, which was triggered by the python snippet above) **works**.

Comment: Have you tried `execute_java('model.classification.Model', '5 6 7 8')` (you may need to remove the use of `splitext`!)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be, that you have to add the directory of your `*.class` file to the classpath! You compiled the class in the directory `model/classification` so the path of your `*.class` file is `model/classification/Model.class`. For executing this bytecode you need to add the directory to classpath by writing `java -cp model/classification Model`...

This python code works for me:

```
import os.path,subprocess
from subprocess import STDOUT,PIPE

def compile_java(java_file):
    subprocess.check_call(['javac', java_file])

def execute_java(java_file, stdin):
    java_class,ext = os.path.splitext(java_file)

    // I changed the following line by adding the directory to the classpath
    cmd = ['java', '-cp', 'model/classification', java_class]

    proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
    stdout,stderr = proc.communicate(stdin)
    print ('This was "' + stdout + '"')

compile_java(os.path.join('model', 'classification', 'Model.java'))
execute_java('Model.java', '5 6 7 8')
```

In this case, the directory path is relative to the execution directory of your python script!

Comment: I'd sooner guess the problem is that the class is `model.classification.Model` (so `Model` in the package `model.classification`), and not `Model` (or `Model.java` as your code tries) in the `model/classification` folder.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Okay yea that would be also one possible source for this problem...

Comment: @MarkRotteveel But he compiled the class in a sub-directory without adding the directory to classpath so I assumed that the problem is the missing directory and not any package problem...

Comment: No, javac can compile (assuming it doesn't reference other files in that package), but java can't execute that way.