# Is it possible to name output of files in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, console

Is it possible to name every output of files and display it in one single console?

Let's say I have a `main.py` file and a `main.java` file, and I want to run them both in one Python script and seperate the outputs by naming them.

Now I have a python file and it should do this:

```py
# run main.py
# run main.java

# when an output is sent from a file, it should be like this:
output = "{} > {}".format(file, output)
# and then print the output.
```

Let's say the java file would usually display `Hello, World!` but here it would be like this in the console: `main.java > Hello, World!`

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

1. I gave a java and a python file as an example, I just want to name the output of different files, without modifying them.
2. I wanted to run them both as a subprocess and display the outputs with names in one console.

Comment: Not a direct duplicate, but check [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9333791/4727702). When you get the output from Java using this approach, you can format it however you want.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "run them both in one Python script"? Do you mean spawning the Java application as a sub process?

Answer (score 1):

Let's say `main.java` file contains:

```
class main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello, World! from Java");
    }
}
```

and `main.py` file:

```
print("Hello, World! from Python")
```

You can do it by using `subprocess` module in another Python file:

```
import subprocess

java = "{} > {}".format("main.java", subprocess.run("java main.java", shell=True, capture_output=True, text=True).stdout.strip())
print(java)
python = "{} > {}".format("main.py", subprocess.run("python main.py", shell=True, capture_output=True, text=True).stdout.strip())
print(python)
```

The output will be:

> main.java > Hello, World! from Java
>
> main.py > Hello, World! from Python

Comment: This is great! I appreciate your help, but this code waits for the file to be finished and then displays all the output at the same time, is it possible to display the _"live output"_, but still with the prefix??